# Lyrics Translation of Прорвемся Опера

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление

I understand the song except for every mention of Опера.
What does it mean? Google translate says it means Opera, and indeed it sound like the word too, but what is the context? It doesn't make sense to me.

[Song link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiz75KTG94U)

Comment: this is not a service for lyrics translations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Опер` (slang) - is a short form of `оперуполномоченный`, which means `detective` / `tec` / `sleuth`.
Plural form of `опер` is `оперá` (stressed `а`).

So the phrase

> Прорвёмся, оперá

means something like

> Everything will be OK, detectives

Comment: You translated *"Прорвемся"* wrong - it is not just *"Everything will be OK"*, it is "We will survive and win". This is a word from war movies.